# Comparing "Hello 4" to input in C++

Tags: c++, string-comparison

I'm trying to use something like `strcmp` to compare a command like "Hello 4" and keep the 4 as a variable

Something like this:

```
if(strcmp(c, "Hello %d") == 0){
    int num = %d;
}
```

Comment: Sam, I'm putting the C++ tag back on, unless the OP actively objects. OP clearly indicated C++ in the title and has given no indication that this code is C. `strcmp` works perfectly well in C++. If the question was titled vaguely with "C/C++" or something, I wouldn't say anything, but this seems to be a pretty clear C++ question to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), which uses the `scanf`-style percent encoders you're using and takes a string to parse as its argument (as well as pointers to store the successful parses into).

It returns the number of arguments successfully stored, or a negative number in the case of an EOF error. In your case, we'll consider it a successful parse if we successfully store the one argument. If we get a zero, that's a failed parse, and if we get a negative number, that's a premature EOF, so we want the result of `sscanf` to be greater than zero.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  const char* c = "Hello 100";
  int num;
  if (std::sscanf(c, "Hello %d", &num) > 0) {
    std::cout << "Success! " << num << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "Failure..." << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Note that in the `else` branch, the `num` variable won't be assigned, so it will have whatever value your code previously assigned to it (which, in the code sample I've shown here, is nothing at all, hence UB). So be careful not to reference that variable in the failure branch.

Answer (score 1):

[Regular expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) are a way to solve this if you're using C++ and not simply compiling C with a C++ compiler.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main() {
    std::string foo = "hello 4";

    std::smatch matches;

    if (std::regex_match(foo, matches, std::regex("hello (\\d+)"))) {
        std::cout << matches[1] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Using regular expressions makes it trivial to account for varying formatting of the string. E.g. What if there are spaces before or after the items we're looking for?

```
std::regex("\\s*hello\\s+(\\d+)\\s*")
```

Or maybe we want to do that but also make it case-insensitive.

```
std::regex("\\s*hello\\s+(\\d+)\\s*",
           std::regex_constants::icase)
```